# find and replace with multiple for loops in Python

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I want to update a text file so that all consecutive capital letters have a space between them. My approach was to use two `for` loops while reading the file line by line.

```
import sys, fileinput

ActiveFileR = open('text.txt', 'r')
ActiveFileW = open('textW.txt', 'w')

CapAlphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

for line in ActiveFileR:
    for ReChr1 in CapAlphabet:
        for ReChr2 in CapAlphabet:
            ActiveFileW.write(line.replace(ReChr1 + ReChr2, ReChr1 + " " + ReChr2))
```

However, this resulted in 676 (26*26) lines in the output file for each line in the input file. I understand why this happened but do not know how to correct it. I want to keep looping the same line until all spaces have been added before moving on to the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify the line in a local variable, and only write it out once:

```
for line in ActiveFileR:
    newline = line
    for ReChr1 in CapAlphabet:
        for ReChr2 in CapAlphabet:
            newline = newline.replace(ReChr1 + ReChr2, ReChr1 + " " + ReChr2)
    ActiveFileW.write(newline)
```

Comment: By the way, this is a really inefficient solution.  Each line will take 676 iterations, and each iteration has to scan the entire line.  A better solution would probably involve iterating through the characters of the line, or using the re module

Comment: Works great, thanks! I do realize this is a horrible solution, but I really wanted to know how to get it to work this way before moving on.

Comment: For anyone else trying to do this, the right way is to use `import re` and then take advantage of [A-Z] being equivalent to any capital letter. Using this method, there is no need to loop within a line. See [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) for help with the `re` module.